# The usage of preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can I omit the word 'by' in the sentence?

> Attach it to the cup by using masking tape

Is the sentence still grammatically correct if I remove 'by'?

Comment: Yes, it would still be grammatical.

Comment: Seems correct to me with or without 'by'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Attach it to the cup (by) using masking tape.

**By** can be omitted and still leave the sentence grammatically correct. In most cases **using** and **by using** are interchangeable.